# Python search path - python can't find my modules

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm trying to run a script from the commandline, and python is having absolutely none of it:

```
[graffias:~/testing.tustincommercial.com]$ export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`:$PYTHONPATH                                          
[graffias:~/testing.tustincommercial.com]$  python -c 'import oneclickcos.mainapp; mainapp.mail.worker_loop()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named oneclickcos.mainapp
[graffias:~/testing.tustincommercial.com]$ python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 24 2010, 17:44:40)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import oneclickcos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named oneclickcos
>>>
[graffias:~/testing.tustincommercial.com]$ ls ./oneclickcos/mainapp/mail.py
./oneclickcos/mainapp/mail.py
[graffias:~/testing.tustincommercial.com]$
```

Any ideas?

**Note for the unwary:** The command above should be `$python -c 'import oneclickcos.mainapp.mail; oneclickcos.mainapp.mail.worker_loop()'` (another valid variant).

Comment: In 2.6 I can `export PYTHONPATH="/a/b/c:/a/b/d"` and import modules inside those folders without issue.  Except on one particular machine I have at home.  On that box I can only have one path in PYTHONPATH or it won't import anything.  I concluded that the interpreter on that box was not compiled correctly.  Maybe you are facing a similar issue...

Comment: I can't see you adding the path to the parent-dir of your module to `sys.path`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a `__init__.py` in `oneclickcos/` and in `oneclickcos/mainapp/`? If not, put one in and try again — that could cause the problem you're seeing.

For more, see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 3):

In order to import from folders like that, they have to be setup as [packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Do `oneclickcos` and `mainapp` have `__init__.py` files in them?